# How do I connect to my own shared folders on a Mac?

Tags: mac, network, windows, sharing, smb

On my Windows 8 PC, I can go to the "Network" page to see all networked computers, including my own. On my Mac, on the "Network" page I can see all networked computers, EXCEPT my own.

I'd like to be able to see the shared contents of my own computer. Is there any way to get it to show on the "Network" page, or at least manually connect to it somehow? I'm sharing files via SMB. I tried combinations like connecting to `smb://localhost`, `smb://192.168.1.xxx` (where `xxx` is my local computer), etc. but these don't work.

Comment: your network has any domain or workgroup for your local network?

Comment: Yep it has a WINS workgroup, which is how I share with my Windows computers.